# Send FCM when a node is changed using Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send notification to `Customers` whenever the `Orderstatus` node is changed to `1` in the Realtime Database.

But Push Notifications are sent whenever there is a change in the `Orders` node.

I can validate the value of the `Orderstatus` from the snapshot & send notification only when the status is `1`. But I want to trigger the cloud functions when the `Orderstatus` is `1`.

If I change the path to `/S01/Orders/{pushId}/orderStatus`. Then I can't get the customerEmail

Please Guide me  a best way to handle this ....

[image]

**CODE**

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.shopperAlert = functions.database.ref('/S01/Orders/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {

        var eventSnapshot = event.data;
        var customerEmail = eventSnapshot.child("orderedBy").val();
        console.log(customerEmail);

        const getInstanceIdPromise = admin.database().ref('S01/Customers/' + customerEmail + '/Token/').once('value');

        return Promise.all([getInstanceIdPromise]).then(results => {
            const instanceId = results[0].val();

            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "Hey",
                    body: "Your Order is on the Way!"
                }
            };

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(instanceId.FCM, payload)
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log("Successfully sent message:", response);
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message:", error);
                });

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you can't filter the trigger of a function depending on the data that changed.  It will be triggered *any* time *any* of the data under the reference path changes.  You have to check inside your function if the data change in a way that you want to act on.

Alternately, if you want to listen more deeply at "orderstatus", you can always query the database again inside your function to get the other data you need to work with.  `event.data.ref` contains a [Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference) to the path that triggered your function, and you can use that to navigate and query the database to find other data you're looking for.  Be sure to also study the [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) that does a lot of similar things to what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
exports.shopperAlert = functions.database.ref('/S01/Orders/{pushId}')
    .onWrite(event => {
      const order = event.data.val();
      const status = order.orderStatus;
      if(status == 1){
           // send notification
      }else{
           // do something
     }
});
```